The dual space of continuous maps
What is the topological dual space of $C_0(\Omega)$ where

$\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ open
$C_0(\Omega)$ is the set of all continuous functions on $\Omega$ which tend to zero approching the edge $\partial\Omega$ (in the Alexandroff extention)
The topology on $C_0(\Omega)$ is given by the seminorm family $\{p_K\}_{K\subset\Omega\text{ compact}}$, where $p_K(f)=||f||_{\infty, K}$

and are there some connections between that dual and Radon measures?

The topology induced by seminorms is not the direct limit topology, because the union of the spaces in the direct limit is not the whole $C_0(\Omega)$. See this answer for detailed explanation.
